# Aggregate in time intervals

Tags: r, time-series

I want to analyze some measurment data in R

```
> head(data)
                 Time     Val
1 2011-12-01 10:11:21      20
2 2011-12-01 10:11:24       0
3 2011-12-01 10:11:24      30
4 2011-12-01 10:11:25       0
5 2011-12-01 10:11:29      80
6 2011-12-01 10:13:31       0
```

I experimented both with Zoo and with as.Date, but none of them led to an answer to the following questions:

1. How can I plot a histogram per minute over the 24 hours of the day?
2. How can I calculate and plot the mean value for each day (not day of month but day single day)?

Answer (score 6):

Get help on `?aggregate` and `?cut.Date`.

Something like:

```
aggregate (z, format (index (z), "%M"), sum)
```

and

```
aggregate (z, cut (as.Date (index (z)), breaks="day"), mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

plyr package is well-suited for the task. There are a few guides around here: http://plyr.had.co.nz
You should assign a value of a factor variable to each of the periods you want to analyze separately - I don't know of the shortcuts, so you may just try applying substr() to your Time variable. Then apply different functions (like mean()) to each of the groups with plyr. For plotting you may use either ggplot package from the same author or lattice.

Comment: I am new to R (learned it today as a Comp. Sc.) and I feel as if plyr is too much for my needs?

Comment: I find it very intuitive (much more so than e.g. ggplot) and the examples in the Hadley's guide are very illustrative. If you have 20 minutes to devote to the problem, spend them reading the file and you'll be well equipped for anything that comes up in the future.